# Increase number of coordinates in KML google earth

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth

Currently I have a route plotted by Google Earth automatically from point A to B.
In the KML files, the LineString coordinates show quite a number of points, but it not enough for my project.  Is there a way to increase the coordinates generated automatically? or is there any formular that I can use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you can explain *why* you need more points.

Generally speaking, you can split each segment by adding another point between two points.

Something like:

```
splitLat = (lat1 + lat2)/2.0;
splitLng = (lng1 + lng2)/2.0;
```

resulting in:

```
<coordinates>
...
lat1, lat2, 0
splitlat, splitLng, 0
lat2, lng2, 0
...
</coordinates>
```

Comment: Let me summarised what am I trying to do. 
I have a few markers along the road, and a vehicle is moving along the road and would like to scan for the next marker in sequence.  I managed to scan the marker provided if the vehicle is near to the marker.  Problem comes when it skips.  Hence, I will be using many of these coordinate in between to get direction and as a hop by hop to get the next marker.  May be someone has a better idea how this could be solved.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried using your technique.  If I have 2 points which in between there is a curve road, then the coordinate won't fall on the road.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: _Haven't tried it myself but..._ you can use `DirectionService` for the job.

Assuming _me_ is between points A and B, compute the travel time A->me and me->B. If A and B are the closest point on a route, this should work OK. There may be some unpredictability in the results if conditions have changed between the time you produced the original route and when you compute A-me-B (e.g. traffic) - but you probably want to notify the user anyway...

Comment: I ended up using Google Earth to compute the dot in between.  This is not something I was look for but it do the job.